# BroadBand to Ethernet converter

Tags: network

we will have PaloAlto Firewall to use it in our SOC network and the line that we have  is 100M broadband Internet, please I need your help to find a solution to convert the available 100M broadband connection to ethernet type.

Comment: Broadband can mean a lot of things. What, specific, layer-1/layer-2 protocol do you mean, and on which medium is it delivered?

Answer (score 2):

Most "broadband" services are delivered via Ethernet - no "converter" needed.

If your service is just a raw xDSL wire or a fiber you'll need a router with the appropriate interface, or a transceiver or line interface for your Palo Alto.